# How to take the value of a multi-select dropdown and later turn value into individual checkboxes in SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How to take the value of a multi-select dropdown and later turn them into individual checkboxes.
For example.
My multiple select dropdown, I selected - Aerosmith, Boston, Cars.
The field value would now become : Aerosmith; Boston; Cars.
How can I make it so that I can take all three aforementioned and turn them into an individual checkboxes ( yes / no ) referencing the initial dropdown multiple select box.

[image]

Comment: If on 2013, use JSLink to override the field rending. Else use jQuery to read the value and create individual checkboxes.

Comment: Hello Aveenav, I just updated that I'm using 2010. I'm not a coder unfortunately but where would I find jquery to that? Thank you.

Comment: That is a very specific scenario. I doubt that you will find ready-made jQuery that does that. You'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Do you want this to be a permanent change for all items? You could write a PowerShell script to copy all the data over into a new choice field.

Comment: Hello everyone and thanks. MIiiikkeee! :) Where to go to learn what powershell I would need to do this please?